# Mysql - use query results for another query

Tags: mysql, procedure, information-schema

I want to find some specific Columns of a database from `Information_schema.Columns` and edit those columns type. I don't know how can I use the result of my first query from Information_schema for making another query to edit columns.
Also I have to do it in MySQL, not PHP.

I've read about Procedures a little , but it was confusing. Acutally I've never done much with mysql.

I would really appreciate if anyone can show me the path or any tutorial.
thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean _edit those columns type_? Are you trying to change a table's column's data type (i.e., int to decimal(8,2))?

Comment: Information_schema is read only (system) database.

Comment: @AgRizzo : yes, I want to change every decimal(12,4) to decimal (14,4)

Comment: @Devart : I know that it's readonly, and I don't want to edit that db,  I want to use it to edit another database

Comment: You need to modify tables/columns directly, e.g. using ALTER TABLE statement or using MySQL GUI tool.

Comment: you can merge your alter query with information schema to make it dynamic. Answered your question below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this could be what you are looking for. dynamic alter query:

```
SELECT CONCAT('ALTER TABLE `my_table` ', 
  GROUP_CONCAT(' CHANGE COLUMN `', COLUMN_NAME , '` ',
    ' `', COLUMN_NAME , '` DECIMAL (14,4)')) 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'my_db' AND TABLE_NAME = 'my_table'
INTO @sql;

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;

EXECUTE stmt;
```

you can use a cursor in stored procedure to apply this to all tables.

```
  DECLARE curs CURSOR FOR  SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'my_db';
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET bDone = 1;
  OPEN curs;

  SET bDone = 0;
  REPEAT
    FETCH curs INTO table_name;

    IF table_name
       /*alter query*/
    END IF;
  UNTIL bDone END REPEAT;

  CLOSE curs;
```

Comment: That is really a neat piece of code! but how can I make the table name, dynamic too? I mean just the database is Static.

Comment: well you can only execute one alter table in one query. you could write a procedure and loop this for all tables in that database

Comment: when I put my db name in TABLE_SCHEMA = 'my_db' and run the query, it seems that it has an 1064 error

Comment: please paste the complete error. you probably don't have any results returned from that query.

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE curs CURSOR FOR SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE' at line 1

Comment: you need to put that block into a procedure. check this tutorial: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?98,358569